# Laravel ajax link doesn't work when I form the html string

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code in FreelancerControler:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = User::where('name','LIKE',$request->name.'%')->where('role','freelancer')->get();
            $output = '';
            if (count($data)>0) {
                foreach ($data as $user) {
                    $output .= ' <div class="row freelancer p-1 m-1">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <img src="'.$user->avatar.'" height="100px" width="100px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <h3><a href={{route("profile",["id"=>'.$user->id.'])}}>'.$user->name.'}}</a></h3>
                        <p>'.$user->profile->title.'</p>
                        <p>'.$user->profile->about.'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                }
            }else {
                $output .= 'No Data Found';
            }

            return $output;
        }

        return view('autosearch');  
    }
```

My problem is in this line:

```
<h3><a href={{route("profile",["id"=>'.$user->id.'])}}>'.$user->name.'}}</a></h3>
```

its output is a broken links with this text: `"3])}}>Karam}}"` , as the user_id is 3 and user_name is Karam.

Comment: do you actually want this `<a href="{{ route("profile", ["id" => $user->id]) }}">{{ $user->name }}</a>`?

Comment: yes this is what I want except the single quotes for href

Comment: Don't use Blade syntax in your controller. Use it in views. You return HTML which doesn't get parsed by Blade

Comment: @brombeer It was working fine until I added the laravel route !

Comment: Yes, because you are using Blade syntax for the route. That doesn't get parsed. Better to _not_ return HTML from your controller but pass your data to a view

Comment: please try this : <h3><a href="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">{{ $user->name }}</a></h3>

Comment: Try this : <h3><a href='.route("profile",["id"=>'.$user->id.']).'>'.$user->name.'}}</a></h3>

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? If you print invalid markup, that is not a PHP or AJAX related problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the route function in controller but using a concatenations
something like this

```
               foreach ($data as $user) {
                    $output .= ' <div class="row freelancer p-1 m-1">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <img src="'.$user->avatar.'" height="100px" width="100px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <h3><a href='.route("profile",["id"=>$user->id]).'>'.$user->name.'</a></h3>
                        <p>'.$user->profile->title.'</p>
                        <p>'.$user->profile->about.'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error:

```
<h3><a href={{route("profile",["id"=>'.$user->id.'])}}>'.$user->name.'}}</a></h3>
```

you may use this one:

```
<h3><a href="'.route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]).'">'.$user->name.'</a></h3>
```

This will put the value instead of blade format to perform additional step in ajax to render.

Comment: That edit didn't really _fix_ the answer, `{{ $user->name }}` will still not work outside of Blade

Comment: The code you've shared does not look like code that should be used in Blade

Comment: @NicoHaase
He has copied my code if you have seen :-D

Comment: No, Muhammad hasn't. Kamran added the code

Comment: Why is Kamran Allana making all the changes to your code?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Ohh Sowieee I didnt see the edits

Comment: @PunitGajjar you have answered right, which was the same as I've edited on MuhammadUmair 's post and so added to further explain that well if you remove blade from the code then this would be ;)

Comment: Please don't copy code from other answers into your own

Comment: @NicoHaase we are here to improve and explain the best answer so that's why edited for better explanation, sorry my bad I remove that further code and request MuhammadUmair to approve.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair kindly approve the edit.

Comment: @KamranAllana "_which was the same as I've edited on MuhammadUmair 's post_" The first changes you made was to remove code from an answer. Then Punit posted his answer and you copied it. That's not the same as you've edited. Also, you can always post your own answer

Comment: @brombeer check the history I've added that but answer was genuine first in one liner, also if you remove the blade from the loop code then it would be same answer from whomever you fix that.
Well next time will post instead of edit in this type.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair I'll revoke my downvote since someone else made those faulty changes

Comment: @brombeer yes that was the thing but I've seen the edit was right with extra code so that's why I approved.

Comment: Well @PunitGajjar is approved and have a great day, next time I'll take care of it.